# Passing strongly typed property name as argument

Tags: c#, lambda, strong-typing

I have a collection of `IEnumerable<School>` that is being passed to an extension
method that populates a `DropDownList`. I would also like to pass the
`DataValueField` and `DataTextField` as an argument but I wanted them to be
strongly typed.

Basically, I don't want to pass a `string` for the `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` arguments, it's error prone.

```
public static void populateDropDownList<T>(this DropDownList source,
        IEnumerable<T> dataSource,
        Func<T, string> dataValueField,
        Func<T, string> dataTextField) {
    source.DataValueField = dataValueField; //<-- this is wrong
    source.DataTextField = dataTextField; //<-- this is wrong
    source.DataSource = dataSource;
    source.DataBind();
}
```

Called like so...

```
myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(states,
        school => school.stateCode,
        school => school.stateName);
```

My question is, how can I pass the `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` strongly typed as an argument to populateDropDownList?

Comment: I don't understand those fields are of type string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based off Jon's answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984194/547071) post, it gave me an idea. I passed the `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` as `Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>>` to my extension method. I created a method that accepts that expression and returns the `MemberInfo` for that property. Then all I have to call is `.Name` and I've got my `string`.

Oh, and I changed the extension method name to `populate`, it was ugly.

```
public static void populate<TObject, TProperty>(
        this DropDownList source, 
        IEnumerable<TObject> dataSource, 
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> dataValueField, 
        Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> dataTextField) {
    source.DataValueField = getMemberInfo(dataValueField).Name;
    source.DataTextField = getMemberInfo(dataTextField).Name;
    source.DataSource = dataSource;
    source.DataBind();
}

private static MemberInfo getMemberInfo<TObject, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> expression) {
    var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if(member != null) {
        return member.Member;
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Member does not exist.");
}
```

Called like so...

```
myDropDownList.populate(states,
    school => school.stateCode,
    school => school.stateName);
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, that in idiomatic C# you would name the method `Populate` - using **PascalCase**.

Answer (score 4):

*If* you're only trying to use property chains, you could change the parameter to `Expression<Func<T, string>>` and then extract the property names involved - you'll need to dissect the [`Expression<TDelegate>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) you get... you'd expect that the [`Body`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body.aspx) will be a [`MemberExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.aspx) representing a property access. If you've got more than one (`school.address.FirstLine`) then the target expression of one member access will be another one, etc.

From that, you can build up a string to use in the `DataValueField` (and the `DataTextField`). Of course, the caller can still screw you over:

```
myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(states,
    school => school.stateCode.GetHashCode().ToString(),
    school => school.stateName);
```

... but you can detect it and throw an exception, and you're still refactor-proof for *good* callers.

Answer (score 0):

With what you were trying, even if you did get it to compile/run, it would still be wrong because the Value & Text fields would've been set to a value in the list instead of the property name (ie, `DataValueField = "TX"; DataTextField = "Texas";` instead of `DataValueField = "stateCode"; DataTextField = "stateName";` like you really want).

```
public static void populateDropDownList<T>(this DropDownList source,
        IEnumerable<T> dataSource,
        Func<string> dataValueField,
        Func<string> dataTextField) {
    source.DataValueField = dataValueField();
    source.DataTextField = dataTextField();
    source.DataSource = dataSource;
    source.DataBind();
}

myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(states,
        "stateCode",
        "stateName");
```