# C# passing a list of strongly typed property names

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list, lambda

I'm looking for a way to pass in a list of strongly typed property names into a method that I can then dissect and get the properties that the caller is interested in. The reason I want to do this is to have a copy method that only copies the fields the user specifies. Right now, the method takes a list of strings to use with the Getvalues and get properties methods in reflection, but I want to guard against refactoring of properties and the strings not being updated by the developer.

I found this article [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074202/passing-strongly-typed-property-name-as-argument), but unfortunately, it does not do a list.  I can do something like:

```
public static void Copy(Expression<Func<TObject>> propertiesToCopy )
{
}
```

And then have the caller do

```
PropertyCopier<List<string>>.Copy(() => data);
```

But then I have to specify how many properties the caller can have like this:

```
public static void Copy(Expression<Func<TObject>> propertiesToCopy,Expression<Func<TObject>> propertiesToCopy2, Expression<Func<TObject>> propertiesToCopy3 )
{
}
```

This would allow for three properties. Is there anyway to add it to a List or Queryable<> to allow as many properties as the caller wants? I tried using the Add in List and having the Expression

Thanks in advance

Edit: I did find a few articles this evening that refer to using the C# **param** keyword to accomplish this. Are there any better or more efficient ways, or is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Are you doing type-mapping with this? If so, you might want to look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: What is wrong with `List<Func<Object>> propertiesToCopy`?

Comment: Take a look at [Get Custom Attributes from Lambda Property Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1560950/580951)

Comment: Andrei, I believe when I tried that, using the Add() method was not happy about adding them in, is this better than using the params?

Comment: @MatthewWatson - I don't want to use something that does it for me. I am trying to use as little third party stuff on this particular project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword to define a method that takes a variable number of arguments:

```
public static void PrintPropertyNames<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties)
{
    foreach (var p in properties)
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)p.Body).Operand;
        string memberName = expression.Member.Name;
        Console.WriteLine(memberName);
    }
}
```

For instance, you could call the **PrintPropertyNames** method passing two expressions:

```
PrintPropertyNames<FileInfo>(f => f.Attributes, f => f.CreationTime);
```

This example displays the following output to the console:

> ```
> Attributes
> CreationTime
> ```