# Property binding to web controls in asp.net with linq and reflection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, reflection, properties

I'd like to "bind" properties from a DTO to corresponding controls, for example checkboxlists or textboxes.  This is so that I can use a dto (passed through the querystring) to set the initial state of the control, and then have the control set it's value to the dto when it comes time to leave the page.  I could do this with two mapping functions (control->DTO, DTO->Control) but instead I'm using Linq and Reflection to maintain a list of property<->control relationships.

I've never done this before and I suspect there may be a better way ... how would you maintain a property<->control relationship?

Here is the code I've used:

```
Public Class ObjectPropertyMapper

    ''' <summary>Provides a binding of a control to one or more properties in a DTO.</summary>
    Private Class ControlBinding

        ''' <summary>A reference to the control which will be bound.</summary>
        Public Property Control As Control

        ''' <summary>The property(ies) which the control will be bound to.</summary>
        Public Property Props As New List(Of PropertyInfo)

        Public Sub New(ctrl As Control, props As IEnumerable(Of PropertyInfo))
            Me.Control = ctrl
            Me.Props.AddRange(props)
        End Sub
    End Class

    ''' <summary>A list of all the control to dto bindings for this page.</summary>
    Private Property ControlBindings As New List(Of ControlBinding)

    ''' <summary>Returns the property info from a linq expression.</summary>
    Private Function GetPropertyFromExpression(Of T)(linqExpression As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T))) As PropertyInfo
        If TypeOf linqExpression.Body Is MemberExpression Then
            Return DirectCast(linqExpression.Body, MemberExpression).Member
        Else
            Dim op = (CType(linqExpression.Body, UnaryExpression).Operand)
            Return DirectCast(op, MemberExpression).Member
        End If
    End Function

    ''' <summary>Binds a control to a single property of the DTO.
    ''' Usage: BindControlToProperty(cblFundTypes, Function() Me.SearchParams.FundTypeIDs) ...  </summary>
    Protected Overloads Sub BindControlToProperty(Of T)(ctrl As Control, linqExpression As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T)))
        ' This works by passing through a linq expression, which in turn has a reference to the property.  
        ' We can therefore extract the property from the linq expression, allowing us to store a reference to the property against the reference to the control
        Dim prop As PropertyInfo = GetPropertyFromExpression(linqExpression)

        ControlBindings.Add(New ControlBinding(ctrl, {prop}))
    End Sub

End Class
```

And the consumer:

```
Public Class MyPage
    Public Sub OnLoad
        BindControlToProperty(myCheckBoxList, Function() MyDTO.IntListProperty)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only alternate method I found was projecting properties onto an anonymous type, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984190/767599

An example would be:

```
Public Class exampleDTO
    Public Property MyProp1 As String
    Public Property MyProp2 As String
End Class

Public Function GetVariableName(Of T)(obj As t) As String
    Dim properties As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo() = obj.GetType.GetProperties
    If properties.Length = 1 Then
        Return properties(0).Name
    Else : Throw New Exception
    End If
End Function

Public Sub BindToControl(Of T)(ctrl As Control, prop As T)
    Response.Write(GetVariableName(prop))
End Sub

Public Sub Main
    Dim c As New Control
    Dim dto As New exampleDTO
    BindToControl(c, (New With {dto.MyProp1}))
End Sub
```

However I have no idea which solution is "better".